# How to make a 2D array of different objects for a game

Tags: java, arrays

I am fairly new to Java and I'm trying to make a text-based game for one of my class.
What I know is when you make a 2 dimensional array it's content must be whatever it's date type. Like, Int[][] array = new int[3][3]. With this, I can only store integers in this 2D array. However, I want to make a tile/map for my game. I want to generate objects of different type and store them in a 2D array so that I can have my Game map. For example, I want to store a Cat object in Row 1 Column 8, then, I want to store a Food object in Row 1 Column 2 and etc...

I have tried to do this, 
It's just a pseudo code for simplicity.

```
Object[][] objectlist = new Object[6][10];
objectlist[0][8] = new Cat("Black");
objectlist[0][2] = new Food("Tuna");
```

Then whenever I call the class methods like.

```
System.out.println(objectlist[0][8].getColor());
System.out.println(objectlist[0][2].getFood());
```

So yeah, pardon me if this is too basic, but like I said, I am new to java.
Anyways, initially this is what I thought of if I'd make a map/tile.
If there's any other approach to to this or another alternative better solution I'd gladly hear you outl.

Comment: Why do you add C++, don't add random tag, thank.

Comment: @Stargateur Sorry! I just clicked whatever was on the suggested tags. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getColor()` or `getFood()` method is not of `Object` class so you need to downcast

Cast according to your object and use method

```
System.out.println(((Cat)objectlist[0][8]).getColor());
System.out.println(((Food)objectlist[0][2]).getFood());
```

You can use `instanceof` operator to test whether the object is an instance of the specified type (class or subclass or interface).

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a generic type of object for each entity represented in this 2D array, you can use Object, as you are doing. But this means, you have to cast everytime you need to property specific to your class.

I would rather say that if the objects are stored in same array, and if they have some common behavior, why not use interfaces.

```
public interface Entity {
    public String behavior();
}

public class Cat implements Entity{
    public String getColor() {
    // something to do
    }

    public String behavior() {
        getColor();
    }
}

public class Food implements Entity{
    public String getFood() {
    // something to do
    }

    public String behavior() {
        getFood();
    }
}
```

And then you can define your array as

```
Entity entities[][] = new Entity[6][10];
entities[0][2] = new Food();
entities[0][8] = new Cat();
```

And print it like

```
System.out.println(entities[0][2].behavior());
System.out.println(entities[0][8].behavior());
```

No casting needed, and no need to know what method needs to be called for each object.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to proper class object is needed. It's better to check if the object is an instance of that class before cast.

```
if (objectlist[0][8] instanceof Cat) {
    System.out.println(((Cat)objectlist[0][8]).getColor());
}
```